# ¿Existe una función como input() pero que sea temporal?¿O alguna forma de implementarla?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Voy a tener un programa ejecutandose mucho tiempo (puede que días) y quiero detenerlo de vez en cuando asegurandome de que termina en el lugar correcto.

Lo que tengo es simple, es un loop for mas o menos así:

```
inicio = read_log()

for i in range(inicio, final):
 func1(i)
 func2(i) 
 func3(i)
 write_log(i)
```

Y me gustaría hacer algo así para asegurarme de que el archivo.log se escribe y poder recordar al día siguiente por donde quedó el trabajo y retomarlo por el mismo punto.

```
inicio = read_log()

for i in range(inicio, final):
 func1(i)
 func2(i)
 func3(i) 
 write_log(i)
 letra = input("El programa continuará su ejecucion en 3 segundos si no pulsa la letra n")
 if letra=="n":
  break
```

Evidentemente con el imput() normal no se puede. Me gustaria saber si hay otra función que lo haga. O alguna manera de poder hacer esto.

Comment: ¿Para que sistema operativo lo necesitas? En *NIX es relativamente simple de implementar usando señales.

Comment: Lo voy a usar con windows... tal vez pueda hacerlo con linux usando Virtualbox... lo que pasa es que si lo hago así el navegador me va a ir mucho mas lento y va a tardar el doble... porque es un programa hecho con Selenium que voy a usar para cargar miles de productos e imagenes en la base de datos de una tienda online. calculo que puede tardar unos 15  dias en terminar (si trabaja continuamente sin descanso) hubiera sido mas fácil si me hubiesen dejado hacer consultas via SQL pero no ha sido posible así que tengo que hacerlo así. He usado señales en C con linux ¿Es posible hacelo en Windows?

Answer (score 4):

Después de mucho buscar he dado con dos posibles soluciones que funcionan en Windows.. La primera y la que mas me gusta para mi caso concreto es esta.

```
import threading, msvcrt
import sys

def readInput( caption, default, timeout = 5):

    start_time = time.time()
    sys.stdout.write('%s(%s):'%(caption, default))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    input = ''
    while True:
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            byte_arr = msvcrt.getche()
            if ord(byte_arr) == 13: # enter_key
                break
            elif ord(byte_arr) >= 32: #space_char
                input += "".join(map(chr,byte_arr))
        if len(input) == 0 and (time.time() - start_time) > timeout:
            print("timing out, using default value.")
            break

    print('')  # needed to move to next line
    if len(input) > 0:
        return input
    else:
        return default
```

Se usa así:

```
 #and some examples of usage
 ans = readInput('Please type a name', 'john') 
 print ('The name is %s' % ans)
 ans = readInput('Please enter a number', 10 ) 
 print ('The number is %s' % ans )
```

FUENTE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933399/how-to-set-time-limit-on-raw-input/2933423#2933423

La segunda usa ventanas y dialogos... una buena alternativa si no hubiera encontrado la anterior:

```
import tkinter as tk

def W_Input (label='Input dialog box', timeout=5000):
    w = tk.Tk()
    w.title(label)
    W_Input.data=''
    wFrame = tk.Frame(w, background="light yellow", padx=20, pady=20)
    wFrame.pack()
    wEntryBox = tk.Entry(wFrame, background="white", width=50)
    wEntryBox.focus_force()
    wEntryBox.pack()

    def fin():
        W_Input.data = str(wEntryBox.get())
        w.destroy()
    wSubmitButton = tk.Button(w, text='OK', command=fin, default='active')
    wSubmitButton.pack()

# --- optionnal extra code in order to have a stroke on "Return" equivalent to a mouse click on the OK button
    def fin_R(event):  fin()
    w.bind("<Return>", fin_R)
# --- END extra code --- 

    w.after(timeout, w.destroy) # This is the KEY INSTRUCTION that destroys the dialog box after the given timeout in millisecondsd
    w.mainloop()
```

Se usa así:

```
 W_Input() # can be called with 2 parameter, the window title (string), and the timeout duration in miliseconds
 if W_Input.data : print('\nYou entered this : ', W_Input.data, end=2*'\n')
 else : print('\nNothing was entered \n')
```

FUENTE:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933399/how-to-set-time-limit-on-raw-input/2933423#2933423